# How to convert infinite number (e.g 6.983333) to get exact time (e.g 6:59:00) without losing any time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, math

How to convert 6.983333 to 6:59 using code. When i convert, it gives me the answer 6:58 using the following code in javascript.

```
function  ConvertDecimalToHours(durationInHours)
{
    let durationInMinutes = durationInHours * 60;
    let hours = Math.floor(durationInHours);
    let minutes = Math.floor(durationInMinutes % 60);  
    let duration = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
    return duration;
}
```

i used the following calculator and it gives me correct answer for the value i am giving (value: 6.983333):

https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/decimal-to-time-calculator.php

Comment: Pick **one** language tag please. **Edit:** Since your code is in JavaScript, I've removed the [tag:.net] and [tag:typescript] tags.

Comment: You're explicitly using `Math.floor`. If you use `Math.round` instead for the minutes value, you'll get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.round`

```js
function  ConvertDecimalToHours(durationInHours) {
    const durationInMinutes = durationInHours * 60;
    const hours = Math.floor(durationInHours);
    const minutes = Math.round(durationInMinutes % 60);  
    const duration = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
    return duration;
}

const res = ConvertDecimalToHours(6.983333);

// Result
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `Math.round`, not `Math.ceil`.

Comment: Yes, thanx) I've already fixed that

Comment: Should i also use Math.round for hours? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Coder - No, because the partial hours are shown as minutes.